# Running Genymotion/MEmu on a proxy

Tags: networking, windows, android, proxy, genymotion

I am at a place where there is a proxy server along with username/password authentication.
Apps like MEmu/bluestacks/Genymotion cannot run on proxy, so I googled and found some ways to work around this problem - ( before i start i gotta tell that i use both Windows10 and Linux Mint so any workaround for my problem for both platforms would be much appreciated)

1. Using an app which tunnels the whole virtual device through the proxy.

   - **Proxy Droid** - I used this app whith the HTTP authentication and proxy and it works well with the browser and google play store but it fails to run some apps like youtube, clashofclans etc.
   - **Psiphon** - I generally use this app on my mobile phone and it works for all of the apps by routing the device through a Socksv5 proxy, BUT it crashes when I run it on on android emulators. Psiphon connects and simply crashes the whole device in genymotion/MEmu.
   - **Drony** - this app is for those who don't have super user privileges (or simply a phone without root) . It has the option to force user-selected apps to run behind a proxy by linking and passing the traffic through ORBOT, sadly my internet provider has blocked Tor's services and it fails to connect (the browser and google play store work in it but CoC and youtube don't).
2. So in google I found posts related to setting proxy using the advanced options in wifi options, but sadly it works only with the browser.(Genymotion proxy with user/password)
3. I also tried using CCproxy and psiphon3.exe to tunnel my whole PC but it doesn't make MEmu/Bluestacks go through that socksv5 connection.
4. I have set up my `apt.conf` file in linux (alongwith the proxy and authentication) but it too gives only the terminal and software manager access to the internet but fails to do so for Genymotion. I have manually setup proxy in Genymotion (again thanks to - Genymotion proxy with user/password).

......... blah-blah

So ppl help me out please and thanks in advance to anyone who finds a solution XD .

and p.s - if anyone wants any snapshot / anything else that might include some work on my part , just tell me so and i'll be ready to help

cheers - Prakhar Sharma

Answer (score 0):

you need something like corkscrew which provides an ssh vpn to http proxy.

This will allow you to have the ssh vpn node on your computer as the default route to the internet via the proxy. If you use another box (that is not the proxy) as the vpn endpoint then you could allow other machines to access this vpn as well. You may well be violating your networks acceptable use policies in doing this , be polite and respectful of others.

Instructions here 
https://tobrunet.ch/articles/vpn-through-https-proxy-with-ssh/

Apparently it can work on windows but i don't know that OS enough to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Droxy](https://zennolab.com/discussion/threads/droxy-multi-threaded-proxying-for-android-emulators.87047/) for multi-threaded proxying Memu/Nox also